# PHP not loading ENV vars set in /etc/sysconfig/httpd

Tags: apache-http-server, php, environment-variables, drupal

I am running Drupal sites (Apache and PHP), and would like to set some of the values in the settings files to be environment variables. After researching, the proper approach appears to be adding them into the /etc/sysconfig/httpd file. It appears that PHP (mod_php) is not loading the variables.

My /etc/sysconfig/httpd file looks like this -

```
LANG=C
db_server=internaldns.mine.com
db_port=3306
memcache_server1=otherinternaldns.mine.com:11211
```

I am loading the variables in Drupal (which is php 7 (mod_php)) like this -

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
   ...
  'host' => $_ENV['db_server'],
  'port' => $_ENV['db_port'],
   ...
);
```

However, it doesn't appear to be loading the variables, as when I do a status of the site, I see the following -

```
 Drupal version : 8.9.11                                                                             
 Site URI       : http://default                                                                     
 DB driver      : mysql                                                                              
 DB port        :              (THIS SHOULD HAVE THE VARIABLE)
```

When I set the same values without variables they work normally.

Is there some step I am missing here for getting the variable loaded inside of the env?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the passenv directive from the mod_env module, see [mod_env](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html)